# OpenCV Applying Affine transform to single points rather than entire image

Tags: c++, opencv

I've got a Affine transform matrix in OpenCV from the KeypointBasedMotionEstimator class.

It comes in a form like:

```
[1.0008478, -0.0017408683, -10.667297;
0.0011812132, 1.0009096, -3.3626099;
0, 0, 1]
```

I would now like to apply the transform to a vector< Pointf >, so that it will transform each point as it would be if they were in the image.

The OpenCV does not seem to allow transforming points only, the function:

```
 void cv::warpAffine    (   InputArray      src,
    OutputArray     dst,
    InputArray      M,
    Size    dsize,
    int     flags = INTER_LINEAR,
    int     borderMode = BORDER_CONSTANT,
    const Scalar &      borderValue = Scalar() 
)
```

Only seems to take images as inputs and outputs.

Is there a way I can apply an affine transform to single points in OpenCV?

Comment: Equations are in documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html

Answer (score 8):

you can use

`void cv::perspectiveTransform(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray m)`

e.g.

```
cv::Mat yourAffineMatrix(3,3,CV_64FC1);
[...] // fill your transformation matrix

std::vector<cv::Point2f> yourPoints;
yourPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(4,4));
yourPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,0));

std::vector<cv::Point2f> transformedPoints;

cv::perspectiveTransform(yourPoints, transformedPoints, yourAffineMatrix);
```

not sure about Point datatype, but the transformation must have `double` type, e.g. `CV_64FC1`

see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#perspectivetransform too

Answer (score 6):

it's a bit clumsy, but you can matrix-multiply your points manually:

```
// the transformation matrix
Mat_<float> M(3,3); 
M << 1.0008478, -0.0017408683, -10.667297,
     0.0011812132, 1.0009096, -3.3626099,
     0, 0, 1;

// a point
Point2f p(4,4);

// make a Mat for multiplication, 
// must have same type as transformation mat !
Mat_<float> pm(3,1);
pm << p.x,p.y,1.0;

// now , just multiply:
Mat_<float> pr =  M * pm;

// retrieve point:    
Point2f pt(pr(0), pr(1));
cerr << pt << endl;
```

---

```
[-6.67087, 0.645753]
```