# applying cv2.warpAffine on images and polygon annotations simultaneously

Tags: numpy, opencv, matrix, matrix-multiplication, image-segmentation

I apply random perspective transformations on images using OpenCV as following:

```
import cv2

# M: some random transformation operations

wimg = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, dsize=(width, height), borderValue=(114,114,114))
```

I have instance segmentation polygon annotations for each image, and I need to finetune the coordinates according to the new warped image.

How can I do it in a fast way, without converting polygon points to binary images, warping them, and converting back to polygon points?

Comment: Check this SO question and answer by berak. You can then either iterate over every point or construct a 3xn matrix and multiply with your transformation matrix. Both should be just about equally efficient. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194211/opencv-applying-affine-transform-to-single-points-rather-than-entire-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use: [`cv2.transform`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga393164aa54bb9169ce0a8cc44e08ff22)

As stated in OpenCV's documentation: `This function may be used for geometrical transformation of N-dimensional points`