# How to warp an image to an irregular shape in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-manipulation, homography

I wanted to know how to **warp an image into a irregular shape**. Right now, I have this **design (image 1)** and want to warp it into the shape shown in the **mask image (image 2)**. Given that I have points of the vertices for the shape.

[Design Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIygW.jpg)

[Mask Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p2mJ.png)

I tried doing it with **homography OpenCV**, here is the code -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Read source image.
    im_src = cv2.imread('tiled5.jpg')

    pts_src = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 5999], [3999, 0], [3999, 5740], [3999, 5647], [3999, 5560], [4000, 4695], [3999, 5999]])

    # Read destination image.
    im_dst = cv2.imread('DSC_0189.png')

    pts_dst = np.array([[1533, 645], [317, 3567], [2849, 1346], [1619, 4366], [1657, 4273], [1673, 4186], [2191, 3321], [1588, 4626]])

    # Calculate Homography
    h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)

    # Warp source image to destination based on homography
    im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, h, (im_dst.shape[1],im_dst.shape[0]))

    # Display images
    cv2.imshow("Source Image", im_src)
    cv2.imshow("Destination Image", im_dst)
    cv2.imshow("Warped Source Image", im_out)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This was the output - [Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoTsW.jpg)

Not sure why the output image is still a rectangle than the shape shown in the mask image (or an irregular shape). Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Homographies are planar transformations. The output is as intended.  I am not sure what the expected output is supposed to be on your side.  I think what you're after is to warp points along the contour of the mask.  In that case, you need to use `transform`, not `warpPerspective`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66947529/applying-cv2-warpaffine-on-images-and-polygon-annotations-simultaneously

Comment: You can try opencv's cv::ThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, I am trying to warp points along the contour of the mask but I have the points noted of that contour/irregular shape in the pts_dst in my code. I tried changing the code from warpPerspective to transform but apparently the result was of a different color than the source image. Did I miss out on something? What method should be used for getting the matrix?

Comment: @Micka I would have to read about it but until now, I can only find its use in C++, it would be great if you could share some resources.

Comment: Researching more about cv::ThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer, I think I have it now. It definitely warped it into my needed shape but takes a lot of time though. I guess that's a problem I would have to face while working on more than 4 points. Thanks a lot @Micka. Have been working on this for a while now and this fixed it.